# Software Centre Reviews Missing Partially

Tags: software-center, reviews

I have an Ubuntu Unity computer where Software Center has GIMP with 3122 ratings. I gave it 5 () in rating. After that, I have installed Ubuntu Gnome in another computer, and went there to see my review and rating. There are only 1171 ratings for GIMP there. My review is also missing.

What is the reason, and how to fix this issue?

Comment: It may be that one of them is the GIMP snap package, and the other is from apt.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Thanks for the response. How to know the source (that is, apt vs snap)?

Comment: Check if gimp is there in `snap list`, and if `apt search gimp` shows installed.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Thanks. Now I have got the answer.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi  I am in a moral dilemma. Both you and vanadium gave correct answers. I want to select both as correct. You gave the answer first, as a comment. I don't know how to select the comment as the correct answer. I shall select vanadium's answer, but please tell me how to give credits to you also as your comment came first.

Comment: Thanks, but you don't have to give me any credit. Don't worry. Enjoy Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowadays, Ubuntu also supports the new "Snap" package management system in addition to the traditional APT system. Several packages that are available as APT package are also available as Snap. For "Software Centre", these are different packages, and indeed also show as different packages. So your review will appear only with the package where you added your review. You cannot "fix" the issue else than reposting your review also with the other package.

In Ubuntu 21.04, Software centre only shows one entry for the same application, and then allows to select a source if there are multiple sources. Still, reviews are collected for each specific source only.

Comment: Thanks for the response. How to know the source (that is, apt vs snap)?

Comment: Looking to the details of the application: this also shows the source.

Comment: Is there any command to look at the details, other than the one mentioned by Archisman Panigrahi?